# Finding Catholic parish belonging to street in Brno

Tags: parish-register

For the city of Brno (of 1885), I am looking for the birth entry of an individual ([Leopoldine Konstantin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopoldine_Konstantin)). So found the [address of her father](http://www.digitalniknihovna.cz/mzk/view/uuid:8812d5c8-90de-11e0-a36c-0050569d679d?page=uuid:d113583c-90de-11e0-a36c-0050569d679d) and now I am looking for the correct Catholic parish responsible for the street "Schwedengasse". For Vienna I would have a map at https://data.matricula-online.eu/de/oesterreich/wien/, does something similar exist for the city of Brno?

The only thing I found until now which went into this direction would be the in bottom-left corner of the following image but this sadly isn't on a street level: https://www.wikitree.com/photo.php/5/5c/Czech_Images-3.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Digital Archive of Brno (Brünn) has the [1890 census](http://digiarchiv.brno.cz/archive/id/d56d03d9-30da-43f1-9321-9fd8925a0293?datatext=1890***Schreibwaldstrasse***35***2984) (advance to p. 2) with Konstantin, Leopoldina (or Leopoldine) and a birth date of 1886 März (March) 12. There is a column for Geburtsort, politischer Bezirk, Land that contains Brünn, Mähren (Brno, Moravia). In 1890 the family lived at Schreibwaldstrasse 35, having moved from Schwedengasse 4.

Searching for "Schwedengasse" + "Brno" I found an entry on an [unrelated person](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Dole%C5%BEalov%C3%A1-11) who lived at Schwedengasse 6,8 -- and that entry claims that Schwedengasse is now Rooseveltova.

There are sites with [historical](https://www.oldmapsonline.org/en/Brno-City_District#bbox=16.4279898,49.10987953,16.72783453,49.294370749999985&q=&date_from=0&date_to=9999&scale_from=&scale_to=) maps of Brno. On [this map](https://www.discusmedia.com/maps/czech_city_maps/5376/) it appears to say "Schwedeng-" on the road that is marked "Rooseveltova" in the Google map.

Looking at [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rooseveltova+4,+602+00+Brno-st%C5%99ed,+Czechia/@49.1979308,16.6092565,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x471294598f4b0611:0xb23c6b31f13e2bdc!8m2!3d49.1979287!4d16.610596) for Rooseveltova 4, there are two Catholic churches just 2 blocks away: [Kostel sv. Jakuba](https://www.svatyjakub.cz/) (Church of St. Jacob/James) and [Kostel svatého Tomáše](https://svtomas.net/) (Church of St. Thomas). I would start with one of those. Or, you could look at more historical maps to see whether there were other Catholic churches nearby.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I was looking at these records of these particular churches before and wasn't successful but thanks to the census form I now know why, the family was Lutheran (apparently the father converted because I know that [he was born Catholic](https://data.matricula-online.eu/de/oesterreich/wien/01-unsere-liebe-frau-zu-den-schotten/01-53/?pg=117)).

Comment: [Found her!](http://actapublica.eu/matriky/brno/prohlizec/8485/?strana=140)